# Why don't see notifications on 5.0.2 Android update for Sony Z3 Compact

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications, lock-screens, sony-xperia-z3

Just updated to latest 5.0.2 Android on my Z3 compact, but noticed I cannot see any notifications for any apps on the lock screen.  I have tried all settings (show all, not show sensitive etc.) for "when device is locked" setting, but nothing shows up.  Could someone help provide a step-by-step guide on getting notifications to show on the lock screen?  This is extremely frustrating for me, especially if I have to enter my PIN to get the home screen just to look at notifications...  Thanks.

Comment: well have you tried restarting your phone?
if doing that will still be the same, try connecting your phone to pc companion and re update everything or try factory reset.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are using the PIN lock screen. Try changing to something else and hopefully it will work.

I also faced this problem and it disappeared when I changed the lock screen type.

Answer (score 0):

XDA found a workaround. It's your exchange account.  http://forum.xda-developers.com/z3-compact/help/notifications-lollipop-lockscreen-help-t3084398

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings - apps - choose messaging - than tick the box with show notification.

It took me ages to find this.